# How to apply css to certain js script selectively?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi this is my first time asking a question on stack overflow :D

I've managed to move the nav icon & logo to the top when scrolling down by js, but because of CSS transition (`ease out`) at `.nav .menu_btn & .nav .menu_btn .line` it's moving slower than the logo.

**Is there any way that I can selectively apply CSS?**

[image: ![nav icon movement]

**Code so far:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 38) {
      $(".nav .menu_btn").css("margin-top", "-36px");
    } else {
      $(".nav .menu_btn").css("margin-top", "0px");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.nav .btn_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav .menu_btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
}

.nav .menu_btn .line {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out 0ms;
}

.nav .menu_btn .line:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  left: 6px;
  animation-delay: 0.33s;
}

.nav .menu_btn .line:nth-child(2) {
  top: 19px;
  left: 6px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.nav .menu_btn .line:nth-child(3) {
  top: 28px;
  left: 6px;
  animation-delay: 0.66s;
}

.nav .btn_wrapper.clicked .menu_btn .line:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  width: 26px;
}

.nav .btn_wrapper.clicked .menu_btn .line:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  width: 26px;
}

.nav .btn_wrapper.clicked .menu_btn .line:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  transition: all 400ms ease-out 0ms;
  width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="btn_wrapper">
      <div class="menu_btn">
        <div class="line sp_menu_anim"></div>
        <div class="line sp_menu_anim"></div>
        <div class="line sp_menu_anim"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included JQuery cdn in your HTML file?

Comment: open F12 console and see if there is any errors there ...

Comment: Provide a classname to the parent and apply the css to your child based on the class name provided to the parent. .. Tada.. !

Comment: Thanks guys I solved it just removed all the transitions applied on .nav .menu_btn at css file & it's solved!

Comment: Use more specific transition targets (not all)

Comment: you could have added `.nav .menu_btn.no-transition` with props to remove all transitions, and on scroll add/toggle the `.no-transition` class

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that will work great thanks I'll try that

Comment: CSS doesn't act on scripts. It acts on _elements_. If you've found a solution, please post and accept it (or delete your question). Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.